# Discord bot goes offline after 5 minutes on azure app service

Tags: node.js, azure, discord, discord.js, azure-app-service-plans

I made this simple Discord bot and deployed it to Azure app service, but to turn the but online I have to go the the URL of the app service which is already weird. So the bot works with the commands but when i don't type a command for 5 minutes the but goes offline.

Locally this doesn't happen.

I have the "Always on" setting enabled in the service plan config.
Does anyone know why and how this happens? and how to fix this

`package.js`

```
{
  "name": "cookie-bot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "cookie-bot",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "author": "me",
  "dependencies": {
    "azure-storage": "^2.10.3",
    "discord.js": "github:discordjs/discord.js"
  }
}
```

This is my `azure-pipline.yml` deploy script

```
- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: $(environmentName)
    pool: 
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:            
          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy: cookie-bot'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
              appType: 'webAppLinux'
              appName: '$(webAppName)'
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
              runtimeStack: 'NODE|12.9'
              startUpCommand: 'npm run start'
```

`app.js`

```
var Discord = require('discord.js');
var auth = require('./conf/auth.json');

var commandRegistry = require('./core/command.registry');
var pingCommand = require('./lib/commands/ping.command');
var helpCommand = require('./lib/commands/help.command');
var insertTrash = require('./lib/commands/insertTrash.command');
var retreiveTrash = require('./lib/commands/retreiveUser.command');

var bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.on('ready', function (evt) {

});

bot.on('message', msg => {

    if (!msg.author.bot) {
        let messageData = {
            userId: msg.author.id,
            username: msg.author.username,
            channel: msg.author.lastMessageChannelID,
            content: msg.content
        };

        let registry = new commandRegistry(messageData.content);

        registry.registerMentionCommand('!ping', () => {
            new pingCommand(msg).reply(messageData);
        });

        registry.registerMentionCommand('!help', () => {
            new helpCommand(msg).reply(messageData.channel)
        });

        registry.registerMentionCommand('!insert', (commands) => {
            new insertTrash(msg).insert(messageData, commands);
        });

        registry.registerMentionCommand('!get', (commands) => {
            new retreiveTrash(msg).retreive(messageData);
        });


    }

});

bot.login(auth.token);
```

Comment: What tier is the App Service Plan running on? The Free tier doesn't have always on feature.

Comment: I am using the B1 tier

Comment: I don't think B1 is a suitable solution, as it seems to be mainly targeted towards web apps, which probably means that Azure shuts down the service after not receiving traffic for x minutes.

Comment: @ChrisSatchell What would be the right solution here?

Comment: @kaaai3 Unfortunately I haven't worked with Azure, so I'm not able to propose a better solution.

Comment: The only things Always On does is send a ping request to the root of your app every couple minutes, the always on request comes in with the "AlwaysOn" user agent string - so that's one way to detect them.  
Use the "AlwaysOn" user agent string or implement your own pinger which passes through the gateway. All that AlwaysOn does is send a GET HTTP request to the root of your site every 2 minutes